# Issue with creating a new forest and promoting a domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I am creating a forest and domain controller for the first time.  The error I get is:

Error determining whether the target server is already a domain controller: Starting a command on the remote server failed with the following error message: The request for the Windows Remote Shell with ShellId 88BC1A7B-E0D8-48EF-A422-D6EE2579FEF1 failed because the shell was not found on the server. Possible causes are: the specified ShellId is incorrect or the shell no longer exists on the server. Provide the correct ShellId or create a new shell and retry the operation. For more information, see the about_remote_troubleshooting Help topic.

The server used to be part of a domain, but it was removed.  Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Thank You!

Comment: delete the old computer account from active directory users and computers.

Comment: The computer account is not in active directory.  None of that has been configured on this computer.  The computer is not joined to any other domains.